# Is it possible to know the actual length of a rubber length

Tags: macros, plain-tex

The MWE is

```
A \hskip 0pt plus 2pt \foo B
\end
```

Then macro `\foo` will tell me the actual length of the previous `\hskip` in the log file.

Is it possible to write such macro `\foo`? How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly what you ask but as you ask for the information in the log you can do

```
\tracingoutput1
    \showboxbreadth\maxdimen\showboxdepth\maxdimen

A \hskip 0pt plus 2pt  B

\parfillskip 0pt plus .5\hsize
A \hskip 0pt plus 2pt  B

\end
```

which produces

```
..\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 431.83829fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
...\tenrm A
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
...\glue 0.0 plus 2.0
...\tenrm B
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

and

```
..\hbox(6.83331+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 1.81032
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
...\tenrm A
...\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66498 minus 1.11221
...\glue 0.0 plus 2.0
...\tenrm B
...\penalty 10000
...\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 234.87749
...\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

From which you can deduce the first line the infinite glue stretch was used (so the finite 2pt stretch was not used) and in the second line finite stretch was used by a factor of 1.81032

---

If you are using an extended tex such as pdftex then you can measure the space within TeX (most of the effort is setting up the aux file, so it's easier in latex) but

```
%\tracingoutput1
%    \showboxbreadth\maxdimen\showboxdepth\maxdimen

\newread\test
\newwrite\aux
\openin\test=\jobname.aux
\ifeof\test\else
\closein\test
\input\jobname.aux
\fi
\immediate\openout\aux=\jobname.aux
\def\foo#1#2{%
\pdfsavepos
\write\aux{\def\expandafter\string\csname#1Xa\endcsname{\the\pdflastxpos}}%
#2%
\pdfsavepos
\write\aux{\def\expandafter\string\csname#1Xb\endcsname{\the\pdflastxpos}}%
\expandafter\ifx\csname#1Xa\endcsname\relax\else
\wlog{LENGTH: \the\dimexpr\csname#1Xb\endcsname sp-\csname#1Xa\endcsname sp}%
\fi}



%%%%%%%


A \foo{x}{\hskip 0pt plus 2pt }B

\parfillskip 0pt plus .5\hsize
A \foo{y}{\hskip 0pt plus 2pt }B

\end
```

produces

```
LENGTH: 0.0pt
LENGTH: 3.62064pt
```

Confirming the result shown in the classic trace information that the first space has a final length of 0pt and the second a final length of 0pt + 1.81032*2pt = 3.62064pt